# Install a MS SQL database on a server

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to create an application in .NET to install a MS SQL database on a server. I have the complete database and all tables and stored procedures.

This is how it will work:
Basically the user will select the server name, enter his ID and password then select a database from the list. 
After this the installer installs all the tables and stored procedures on the database.

If any one of you used .NET membership, i want a tool similar to ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool (Aspnet_regsql.exe).

I develop asp.net websites and have no idea how to start developing this tool. I have searched on the net, but want to learn the best methord to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is an old article I've written in 2005 for this purpose [Deploy SQL Server databases easily with an Installer class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10032/Deploy-SQL-Server-databases-easily-with-an-Install)

Comment: I have already seen the tutorial. One of the few I could find online. I was wondering with the Database project and WiX installer, is there a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look this links. You can create membership tables and must  call this membership provider in your webconfig

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb